# Looking to return all possible rolls of two dice. The return value is a list which contains tuples

Tags: python, list, loops

I am currently trying to understand how to nest two for loops together before utilizing any comprehension loops. My mission is to return a list of every combination as a tuple, instead i am receiving a list of 6 lists, when i want a list of 36 combinations.

I have tried to iterate over the two ranges.

```
def build_roll_permutations():
  dice = []
  for i in range(1,7):
    dicee = []
    for j in range(1,7):
      dicee.append((i,j))
    dice.append(dicee)
  return dice
```

expected results:

```
[(1,1),(1,2)(1,3)...etc]
```

my results:

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)], [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)], [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)], [(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6)], [(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6)], [(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]]
```

Comment: Your code explicitly builds a list of lists. If you wanted to flatten it, `dice.extend(dicee)` would achieve that.

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of `dicee` and append directly to `dice`.

```
def build_roll_permutations():
  dice = []
  for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(1,7):
      dice.append((i,j))
  return dice
```

Note you can do this with a simple list comprehension

```
def build_roll_permuatations():
    return [(i,j) for i in range(1,7) for j in range(1,7)]
```

or `itertools.product` (since this is, in fact, a product and not a permutation):

```
def build_rolls():
    return list(product(range(1,7), repeat=2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead of append, when modifying `dice`:

```
def build_roll_permutations():
    dice = []
    for i in range(1, 7):
        dicee = []
        for j in range(1, 7):
            dicee.append((i, j))
        dice.extend(dicee)  # line to fix
    return dice


print(build_roll_permutations())
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: As chepner stated, there is no need to use extend because there is no need to build a second list.